# CSS Navigation menu item dissappearing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am currently making a drop down navigation bar for a website. I am having trouble with it because I wanted to stretch the navigation bar accross the whole screen right under the banner. I used width: 100%; to make it do so. But when I hover over the list and the drop down menu appears it stretches across the screen as well. It was because of the position being relevant. I changed it and when I did the drop down menu is white until you hover over one of the li in it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FDrau

Is the link to what i'm working on. Can anyone show me how to fix it?

Comment: If you make the nested UL have a width of auto that seems to fix it for me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xcDAm      EDIT: Tested on Firefox

Comment: Thank you Trav. This helped alot! :)